# NestJS GraphQL - call ResolveField() in nested fields

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

I have a question about how to call `@ResolveField()` category when it is in payload?

```
getProducts(controls: $controls) {
  count
  payload {
    id
    name
    category {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I'm confused here (code below doesn't work):

```js
// I need something like @ResolveField('payload.category', ...) 
@ResolveField('name', () => TypeFunc);
async getCategory(@Parent() product: Product) {
  return this.categoryService.getCategory(product.id);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. You need `@ResolveField('payload')`, and return a payload object which either has a `.category` property or something that can be used to resolve the `category` from.

Comment: Please post more of your code and all the types involved in that query (`Product`, `ProductPayload`, `Category` or something?)

Comment: Thank you, i found my mistake . In my case my class @Resolver() returned another Type which doesnt contain category . Totally i did everything wrong ... now i'm fixing BUT i understood what was wrong.